# Input box field value not display in json format

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

```
<?php
echo "<table  id='example-table' class='table table-bordered table table-hover'>";
echo "<thead><tr class='main-head'>";
echo "<th>S.N.</th>";
echo "<th>Acode</th>";
echo "<th>Aname</th>";
echo "<th>{$lyp_1}</th>";
echo "<th>{$lyp_2}</th>";
echo"<th>Suply</th>";
echo "<th>Sum</th>";
echo "<th>Amount</th>";
echo "</tr></thead>";

$classcode = 'C' . $count;
//$idcode  = $nt[0];
//$classcode = 'C' . $idcounter;
//$classamt  = 'A' .  $idcounter;

$count=1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res_final)) {
    if($row[5]== 's') {
        $row4_info = "";

        if (($row[4]== 'y')&& ($row[5]!= 's')) {
            $row4_info = "<input type='text' id='{$row[0]}' class='A{$count}' value=''>";
        }

        $row5_info = "";

        if ($row[5]== 's') {
            $row5_info = "<input type='text' id='{$row[0]}' class='A{$count}' value='' disabled='disabled'>";
        }

        echo "<tr> <td>". $sn = $startpoint + $count . "</td>
              <td class='C{$count}'>"  .$row[0] ."</td>
              <td >" . $row[1] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row[2] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row[3] . "</td>
              <td class='warning'>" . $row[4] . "</td>
              <td class='warning'>" . $row[5] . "</td>
              <td>" .$row4_info.$row5_info."</td></tr>";
    } 
    else {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $sn = $startpoint + $count . 
              "</td><td class='C{$count}'>"  .$row[0] ."</td>
              <td>" . $row[1] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row[2] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row[3] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row[4] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row[5] . "</td>
              <td>" . "<input type='text' id='{$row[0]}'
              class='A{$count}' value=''  />" . "</td></tr>";
    }

    $count = $count +1;
}

echo "</table>";
echo "<button style='margin-left:30px' id='save' class='button      btn-submit btn btn-primary' name='save'>Save</button>";
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <script src="js/jquery.tabletojson.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.2.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#save').click( function() {
                    var table = $('#example-table').tableToJSON();
                    console.log(table);
                    alert(JSON.stringify(table));
                });
            });
```

I want to get all table value in json when i click save button they show all value in display in alert box.input text box value not show in json.how can i solve this you can see image in that below link
http://www.aventissoft.net/deve/json/json.png

Answer (score 0):

Update your while loop:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res_final)) {
    if($row[5]== 's') {
        $row4_info = "";

        if (($row[4]== 'y')&& ($row[5]!= 's')) {
            $row4_info = "<input type='text' id='".{$row[0]}."' class='A{$count}' value=''>";
        }

        $row5_info = "";

        if ($row[5]== 's') {
            $row5_info = "<input type='text' id='".{$row[0]}."' class='A{$count}' value='' disabled='disabled'>";
        }

        echo "<tr> <td>". $sn = $startpoint + $count . "</td>
              <td class='C{$count}'>"  .$row[0] ."</td>
              <td >" . $row[1] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row[2] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row[3] . "</td>
              <td class='warning'>" . $row[4] . "</td>
              <td class='warning'>" . $row[5] . "</td>
              <td>" .$row4_info.$row5_info."</td></tr>";
    } 
    else {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $sn = $startpoint + $count . 
              "</td><td class='C{$count}'>"  .$row[0] ."</td>
              <td>" . $row[1] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row[2] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row[3] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row[4] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row[5] . "</td>
              <td>" . "<input type='text' id='{$row[0]}'
              class='A{$count}' value=''  />" . "</td></tr>";
    }

    $count = $count +1;
}
```

Also instead of alert try to use console.log(). as in alert due to long string, it is not able to show the whole thing

Comment: did you check the html part?Is it proper html?

Comment: yes it is proper html..if you have another idea so please give me